# how to upload video using RNfetchBlob

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native. I want to upload the video to the server. How to upload video using RNfetchBlob?
Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
upladingVideo = () =>  {
    RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', YOUR_API_URL, {
         'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
         "Accept":"multipart/form-data",
      },[
        {name: YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME, filename: ‘myvidoe.mp4', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(YOUR_LOCAL_VIDEO_URL) },
      ]).then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 'success') {
                // If you will get a success response from your api
                alert(‘Video is uploaded successfully’);
            } else {
               alert(‘Something went wrong’);
            }})
         .catch((err) => {
             alert(err);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches try both. both should work. also, configure your backend to handle blob data or form data if using express nodejs backend then add multer or express-formidable middleware to that specific route.

on frontend both method works
1.

```
`postVideo = (video,url) =>  {
 RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST',url, {
     'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
     "Accept":"multipart/form-data",
     'access-token': AuthToken.token, //token from server
  },[
    //the value of name depends on the key from server
    {name: 'video', filename: 'vid.mp4', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(video.uri) },
  ]).then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 'success') {
            alert("Upload success");
            this.props.navigation.navigate('publish');
        } else {
           alert(response.msg);
        }})
     .catch((err) => {
         alert(err);
    })
}`
```

2.

```
`async startRecording() {
 this.setState({ recording: true });
 // default to mp4 for android as codec is not set
 const { uri, codec = "mp4" } = await this.camera.recordAsync();
 this.setState({ recording: false, processing: true });
 const type = `video/${codec}`;

 const data = new FormData();
 data.append("video", {
   name: "mobile-video-upload",
   type,
   uri
 });

 try {
  await fetch(ENDPOINT, {
  method: "post",
  body: data
  });
  } catch (e) {
   console.error(e);
  }

  this.setState({ processing: false });
  }`
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. From here [ postVideo = (video,url) =>  { ], how to declare the video and url?

Comment: Have you changed this line? { name: 'file', filename: 'vid.mp4', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(response.uri) },

Comment: have, but have this error:  "Can't find variable: response"

Comment: dont pass the data from state. Instead pass the uri ex ..RNFetchBlob.wrap(VideoSource.uri) .

Comment: aslo in..... this.setState({
                VideoSource: {uri: video.uri},
                // no need of data
            });

Comment: video.uri will point to The uri to the local file asset on the device (photo or video) as docs says. Base64 encoding is handled by RNfetchBolob.wrap() method

Comment: I already update my code at the above. You say like this right?  but this will get the error 'Can't find variable: VideoSource'

Comment: It seems like something small that you are missing. Delete the whole code and start writing it again. While understanding the meaning of each line. That's how I approach such problems. Because If this thing is working for others, it should definitely work with you.

Comment: The data only can use RNfetchBlob.wrap() method？

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your data like this. This worked for me and is the latest approach:

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch(
  'POST',
  `${BASE_URL}vehicle/vehicleRegistration`,  //backend base url
  {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data,octet-stream',
  },
  [
    {
      name: 'photo',
      filename: 'vid.mp4',
      data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(vehicleImage.uri),//You have to give the path of your audio, video or image here.
    },

    {
      name: 'email',
      data: user.email,
    }, //add other data like this
    
  ],
)
  .uploadProgress((written, total) => {
    console.log('uploaded', written / total);
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(RetrivedData => {
    console.log('---retrieved data------', RetrivedData);
    Toast.show({
      text1: 'Success',
      text2: 'Vehicle Added to Garage!',
      type: 'success',
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('----Error in adding a comment----', err);
    Toast.show({
      text1: 'Request Failed',
      text2: err?.response?.data?.message,
      type: 'error',
    });
  });
```